# Python script: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, promise, webapi, discourse

I forked this [repo](https://github.com/kitsandkats/ArchiveDiscourse) in order to make my discourse site into a static one. But, I keep getting this message:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It works for most posts, so it could be because the forum I am trying to archive is too large.

This line is most likely causing trouble `posts_json = response.json()['post_stream']['posts']`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I added `print(response.raise_for_status())` and got this message

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.phylobabble.org//t/matrix-data-types/219.json
```

I added `time.sleep(1)` and now it works!

```
# Function that writes out each individual topic page
def write_topic(topic_json):
    topic_download_url = base_url + '/t/' + topic_json['slug'] + '/' + str(topic_json['id'])
    topic_relative_url = 't/' + topic_json['slug'] + '/' + str(topic_json['id'])
    try:
        os.makedirs(topic_relative_url)
    except Exception as err:
        print ('in write_topic error:', 'make directory')
    response = requests.get(topic_download_url + '.json', cookies=jar)
    # posts_json will contain only the first 20 posts in a topic
    posts_json = response.json()['post_stream']['posts']
    # posts_stream will grab all of the post ids for that topic
    posts_stream = response.json()['post_stream']['stream']
    # get rid of first 20 in stream, as they are already in posts_json
    posts_stream = posts_stream[20:]
    # break stream into a list of list chunks of n posts each for lighter requests
    n = 9999999
    chunked_posts_stream = [posts_stream[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(posts_stream) + n - 1) // n)]
    posts_download_url = base_url + '/t/' + str(topic_json['id']) + '/posts.json?'
    # make a request for the content associated with each post id
    # chunk and append it to the posts_json list
    for chunk in chunked_posts_stream:
        formatted_posts_list = ""
        for post_id in chunk:
            formatted_posts_list = formatted_posts_list + 'post_ids[]=' + str(post_id) + '&'
        response = requests.get(posts_download_url + formatted_posts_list, cookies=jar)
        posts_2_json = response.json()['post_stream']['posts']
        posts_json.extend(posts_2_json)
    # generate that HTML
    post_list_string = ""
    for post_json in posts_json:
        post_list_string = post_list_string + post_row(post_json)
    topic_file_string = topic_template \
        .replace("<!-- TOPIC_TITLE -->", topic_json['fancy_title']) \
        .replace("<!-- JUST_SITE_TITLE -->", str(site_title.text)) \
        .replace("<!-- ARCHIVE_BLURB -->", archive_blurb) \
        .replace("<!-- POST_LIST -->", post_list_string)

    f = open(topic_relative_url + '/index.html', 'w')
    f.write(topic_file_string)
    f.close()
```

Comment: You might want to check `response.headers["Content-Type"]` before trying to retrieve JSON from response.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you don't get back a valid json from the get request. Have you checked the status code that you got here if it is a 2xx code? You can also add

```py
response.raise_for_status()
```

to see if that fails and which exception you get.

Comment: Or simply check `response.status_code`. Raising exception is a way if you have complex code structure and need to catch exception on outer scope.